# How to Receive Data and Display Records According to Spinner's Selected Item. In Android's SQLITE DatabaseHelper.java

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Here i am taking n as the variable for data received from Spinner's Selected item from MainActivity.
This is DatabaseHelper(This Code gives Error like no such Column)

```
public Cursor getallData3(String n)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res1 = db1.rawQuery("select  *from  "+ TABLE_NAME2  +" where"+COL_555+ "="+n  ,null);
        return res1;
    }
```

This is Spinner's code and select query's code :

```
   spr3=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        btnsrch=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
n= spr3.getSelectedItem().toString();
        btnsrch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Cursor res = db3.getallData3(n);

                if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                    showmsg2("Error", "No Data Found");
                    return;
                }
                StringBuffer buf1 = new StringBuffer();
                while (res.moveToNext()) {
                    buf1.append("Class's Id number : " + res.getInt(0) + "\n");
                    buf1.append("Class Name : " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                    buf1.append("Class contact  : " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                    buf1.append("Class address : " + res.getString(3) + "\n");
                    buf1.append("Class's Area : " + res.getString(4) + "\n\n");
                    buf1.append("Student's Review : " + res.getString(5) + "\n\n");


                }
                showmsg2("Class Details", buf1.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: One More Thing i Forgot to mention that this code gives me error like no such column

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 errors in your code.
The 1st is that you are missing a space after `where` and before the column `COL_555` and the 2nd is that you pass the parameter `n` unquoted.
Pass the parameter in the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()` so you don't have to worry about quoting:

```
Cursor res1 = db1.rawQuery(
    "select  * from " + TABLE_NAME2 + " where " + COL_555 + " = ?",
    new String[] {n}
);
```